# How to find the value by checking the flag

Tags: pandas

data frame is below

```
uid,col1,col2,flag
1001,a,b,{'a':True,'b':False}
1002,a,b,{'a':False,'b':True}
```

out

```
a
b
```

by checking the flag, if a is `true` then print `a` on the `out` column, if `b` flag is `true` then print `b` on the `out` column

Comment: It's better if you included rows where the flag is `False` as well.

Comment: maybe add some sample output

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) after [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
m=pd.DataFrame(df['flag'].tolist()).fillna(False)
final=df.assign(New=m.dot(m.columns))
print(final)
```

---

```
    uid col1 col2         flag New
0  1001    a    b  {'a': True}   a
1  1002    a    b  {'b': True}   b
```

Comment: i have edited the question, before i have tried with your answer its null for me

Comment: @Nons why do you take only `b` in the second row when both a and b is True?

Comment: @Nons are the rows which has a dict a valid dict or a string rep of a dict. Can you try `df['flag']=df['flag'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before running this code?

Comment: its dict type, we can directly apply

Comment: its dict type, we can directly apply

Comment: @Nons i get the exact same output on my system when I try again and it matches your output

Comment: can you do some `if` condition and check and apply to that function, i am getting so many other error while doing so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204680/discussion-between-anky-91-and-nons).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to evaluate the `flags` column (and `col1` and `col2` won't be used in any way as per your question), then you can simply get the first key from the flags dict where the value is `True`:

```
df.flag.apply(lambda x: next((k for k,v in x.items() if v), ''))
```

(instead of `''` you can, of course, supply any other value for the case that none of the values in the dict is `True`)

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import ast
s = '''uid,col1,col2,flag
1001,a,b,"{'a':True,'b':False}"
1002,a,b,"{'a':False,'b':True}"
1003,a,b,"{'a':True,'b':True}"
1004,a,b,"{'a':False,'b':False}"'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
df.flag = df.flag.map(ast.literal_eval)

df['out'] =  df.flag.apply(lambda x: next((k for k,v in x.items() if v), ''))
```

Result

```
    uid col1 col2                      flag out
0  1001    a    b   {'a': True, 'b': False}   a
1  1002    a    b   {'a': False, 'b': True}   b
2  1003    a    b    {'a': True, 'b': True}   a
3  1004    a    b  {'a': False, 'b': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

We can also use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) 
to convert the dictionary to series, then remove the fake ones with [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) + [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and select a or b from the index with [`Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
s = df['flag'].apply(pd.Series)
df['new']=s[s].stack().index.get_level_values(1)
#df['new']=np.dot(s,s.columns) #or this
print(df)
```

**Method 2:**

We can also check the items with [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and save the key in a list if the value is True.
Finally we use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) if we want to get rid of the list.

```
df['new']=df['flag'].apply(lambda x: [k for k,v in x.items() if v])
df = df.explode('new')
print(df)
```

or **without `apply`**:

```
df=df.assign(new=[[k for k,v in d.items() if v] for d in df['flag']]).explode('new')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    uid col1 col2                     flag new
0  1001    a    b  {'a': True, 'b': False}   a
1  1002    a    b  {'a': False, 'b': True}   b
```